# get the lengths of element of lists of list in R

Tags: r, list, lapply, sapply

Here is my list called dico :

```
dico <- list(list(list(c("dim.", "dimension", "dimensions", "mesures"
), c("45 cm", "45", "45 CM", "0.45m")), list(c("tamano", "volumen", 
"dimension", "talla"), c("45 cm", "45", "0.45 M", "45 centimiento"
)), list(c("measures", "dimension", "measurement"), c("45 cm", 
"0.45 m", "100 inches", "100 pouces"))), list(list(c("poids", 
"poid", "poids net"), c("100 grammes", "100 gr", "100")), list(
    c("peso", "carga", "peso especifico"), c("100 gramos", "100g", 
    "100", "100 g")), list(c("weight", "net wieght", "weight (grammes)"
), c("100 grams", "100", "100 g"))), list(list(c("Batterie oui/non", 
"batterie", "présence batterie"), c("Oui", "batterie", "OUI"
)), list(c("bateria", "bateria si or no", "bateria disponible"
), c("si", "bateria furnindo", "1")), list(c("Battery available", 
"battery", "battery yes or no"), c("yes", "Y", "Battery given"
))))
```

visually it looks like :

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "dim."       "dimension"  "dimensions" "mesures"   

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "45 cm" "45"    "45 CM" "0.45m"


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "tamano"    "volumen"   "dimension" "talla"    

[[1]][[2]][[2]]
[1] "45 cm"          "45"             "0.45 M"         "45 centimiento"


[[1]][[3]]
[[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1] "measures"    "dimension"   "measurement"

[[1]][[3]][[2]]
[1] "45 cm"      "0.45 m"     "100 inches" "100 pouces"



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "poids"     "poid"      "poids net"

[[2]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "100 grammes" "100 gr"      "100"        


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "peso"            "carga"           "peso especifico"

[[2]][[2]][[2]]
[1] "100 gramos" "100g"       "100"        "100 g"     


[[2]][[3]]
[[2]][[3]][[1]]
[1] "weight"           "net wieght"       "weight (grammes)"

[[2]][[3]][[2]]
[1] "100 grams" "100"       "100 g" 
...
```

I want to get all the lengths of all the elements of my list. So I want an output which would look like this :

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] 3   

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] 4


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 4   

[[1]][[2]][[2]]
[1] 4


[[1]][[3]]
[[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1] 3

[[1]][[3]][[2]]
[1] 4



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]][[1]][[2]]
[1] 3      


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]][[2]][[2]]
[1] 4  


[[2]][[3]]
[[2]][[3]][[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]][[3]][[2]]
[1] 3
...
```

I know I should use lapply, sapply and stuff but I got stuck for hours. How would you do it?

Comment: You may need `lapply(dico, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) lapply(y, length)))` to get the expected format.  BTW for the first element, length should be 4 `[1] "dim."       "dimension"  "dimensions" "mesures"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use the recursive version of `lapply` i.e. `rapply`

```
rl <- rapply(dico, length, how="list")
rl
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[[1]][[1]][[1]]
#[1] 4

#[[1]][[1]][[2]]
#[1] 4


#[[1]][[2]]
#[[1]][[2]][[1]]
#[1] 4

#[[1]][[2]][[2]]
#[1] 4
#---
```