# Get the index of the largest list in a list of list in R

Tags: r, list, lapply, sapply

This question builds off of this other question: [get the lengths of element of lists of list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084245/get-the-lengths-of-element-of-lists-of-list-in-r).

Once we get the lengths of the elements in the lists of lists, how do we get the index of the largest list?

My lists of lists `d` looks like:

```
d <- list( list(level = c(1), x = c(10,20,30,40), y = c(55,44,33,22)), 
list(level = c(1), x = c(50,70,23,53, 43), y = c(80,23,54,30, 43)), 
list(level = c(1), x = c(30), y = c(90)))
```

Here's a visual representation

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$level
[1] 1

[[1]]$x
[1] 10 20 30 40

[[1]]$y
[1] 55 44 33 22

[[2]]
[[2]]$level
[1] 1

[[2]]$x
[1] 50 70 23 53 43

[[2]]$y
[1] 80 23 54 30 43

[[3]]
[[3]]$level
[1] 1

[[3]]$x
[1] 30

[[3]]$y
[1] 90
```

The first list of lists has a total of 9 elements, the second list of lists has a total of 11 elements, the third lists of lists has 3 elements.

I'm looking for a command that will return the index `2` since that has the list of lists has the most elements.

Comment: `which.max(lapply(d, function(x) sum(lengths(x))))`

Comment: I appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop through the `list`, extract either the 'x' or 'y' component and get the `lengths` of it, use that to create a logical index for filtering the `lst`

```
l1 <- lengths(sapply(d, `[`, 'x'))
d[l1== max(l1)]

#[[1]]
#[[1]]$level
#[1] 1

#[[1]]$x
#[1] 50 70 23 53 43

#[[1]]$y
#[1] 80 23 54 30 43
```

---

If this has to take into account the total number of elements, loop through the `list` ('d') `unlist` and get the `lengths`

```
l1 <- lengths(lapply(d, unlist))
d[l1 == max(l1)]
```

Comment: `which.max(l1)` would give me the index of the longest lists of list. I appreciate it.

Comment: @cooldood3490  Yes, I used `== max` in case if there are `list` elements having ties for lengths.  then the `which.max` gives the first one, while `==` gives all.  It depends on how you want it